# cannot get datagridview to refresh data

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have the following button click event:

```
private void button_GetTrucks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (textBox_CompanyCode.Text.Length != 3)
  {
    _errorProvider.SetError(button_GetTrucks, "Invalid company code.");
    return;
  }
  textBox_CompanyCode.Enabled = false;
  button_GetTrucks.Enabled = false;

  _corporationId = GetCorporationId(textBox_CompanyCode.Text);
  if(_corporationId == Guid.Empty)
  {
    _errorProvider.SetError(button_GetTrucks, "Could not find company.");
    return;      
  }

  dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
  _soureItemCollection = null;

  textBox_CorporationId.Text = _corporationId.ToString();
  var query = GetTrucks(_corporationId);
  _soureItemCollection = new ObservableCollection<Truck>(query);
  dataGridView1.DataSource = _soureItemCollection;
  MakeDataGridViewPerty();

  button_GetTrucks.Enabled = true;
  textBox_CompanyCode.Enabled = true;      
}

public static List<Truck> GetTrucks(Guid corporationId)
{
  return (from trk in Entity.Trucks
    where trk.CorporationId == corporationId
    orderby trk.TruckNumber
    select trk).ToList();
}
```

When I get the data initially by clicking the button, it works fine. If the data has changed, due to another program changing the data and I click this button again to refresh the data, it stays the same and does not display the changed data.

If I restart the application, click the button, the new data is displayed correctly.

So, it takes me restarting the application to reload the data.

Why is the button click not reloading the data?

Comment: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resetbindings(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: have you debugged / put a break point in that method to check it's getting called and running as you expect it to?

Comment: linq to sql? if so its the downfall of optimistic concurrency.try fetching the data from the database through the context and not using the context itself because it will give you the cached data not the new values,and then you can call GetTrucks().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen where you have to add in a databind to get it to rebind

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = _soureItemCollection;
dataGridView1.Databind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Before this call: `var query = GetTrucks(_corporationId);` place this one first:

```
Entity.Refresh(RefreshMode.OverwriteCurrentValues,Entity.Trucks);
```